# CGAL intersection of line<circular_kernel> and circle<circular_kernel> with circle extremal point processing circular arcs expand

Tags: intersection, cgal

I'm new to using CGAL library and 
trying to get the intersection of line<circular_kernel> and circle<circular_kernel> 
The circular_kernel is Exact_circular_kernel 
In the general case, intersection is just fine 
But there did not have any intersection point if the line is intersect with the extremal points of the circle

**My purpose is to expand a circular arcs. So, I use the center of arcs to construct concentric circles with new radius(arc.radius + CONSTANT C) and do intersect with two lines to get the new start point and new end point of this new arcs**

Here's example of this situation

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_circular_kernel_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Line_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Circle_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Circular_kernel_intersections.h>
#include <vector>    
#include <iterator>

typedef CGAL::Exact_circular_kernel_2   CK;
typedef CK::Point_2                     Point
typedef CK::Circle_2                    Circle;
typedef CK::Line_2                      Line;
typedef CK::FT                          FT;

int main()
{
    // both lines intersect with the circle in extremal point
    Line l1(FT(0), FT(1), FT(-0.3532));
    Line l2(FT(-1), FT(0), FT(2.1838));

    Circle c(Point(FT(2.0138), FT(0.5232)), CGAL::square(0.17));
    /*My circle construction is like this
    double radius = CGAL::sqrt(to_double(CGAL::squared_distance(PointOnArc, c.center())));
    Circle c(ArcCenter, CGAL::squared_distance(radius + EXPAND_GAP));
    */
    typedef typename CGAL::CK2_Intersection_traits<CK, Line, Circle>::type Intersection_result;
    std::vector<Intersection_result> res;
    CGAL::intersection(l1, c, std::back_inserter(res));
    CGAL::intersection(l2, c, std::back_inserter(res));
    
    std::cout << res.size() << '\n'; // should be 2 but it is 0
}
```

Is this caused by precision?
Any suggestion is appreciated, Thanks!

Edit: 
The example above is extracted for represeting this problem 
The size of res is 2 but it seems that only the intersection of l1 and circle get the intersection point(but duplicate once, so the res.size() is 2) 
The correct size of res should be 2 and one for l1 and circle, one for l2 and circle) 
And l1 is horizontal line, and l2 is vertical line 
**After testing, the problem seems to happen if the line is vertical line i.e. no intersection point between vertical line and circle**

Comment: I get 2; CGAL version 5.4.

Comment: @EfiFogel I use CGAL:x64-windows version 5,.4 too. Could u help me? Thanks

Comment: I test it also get 2; Sorry for that, But the coefficient a,b,c of l1 and l2 got from to_double() function and cout in the console. And the circle constructor param of squared_radius is also extracted. I will edit this post to bring it back Thanks.

Comment: Indeed the vertical line does not intersect. The floating point numbers you provide are converted to exact numbers, which results with a non-intersection. FT(2.0138) + sqrt(FT(CGAL::square(0.17)) != FT(2.1838). Even FT(2.0138) + FT(0.17) is not guaranteed to be equal to FT(2.1838)

Comment: @EfiFogel, Sorry to bother u, Is there any approach to resolve this floating point precision problem?

Comment: You need to use an exact number type, and in particular, the type provided by the kernel, namely, CK::FT. If you have Gmp, it is defined as CGAL::Gmpq, which is a rational number type, e.g., CK::FT(5, 2).

Comment: @EfiFogel I've used typedef CK::FT FT, Is that I've done that use the exact number type?

Comment: Notice that CK::FT is the exact rational number type that can be used for input coordinates and square radius. The exact number type of generated points (due to, e.g., intersections) is different, as it is not rational any longer. (It has a square root.)

Comment: @EfiFogel Thanks for your patience and infromation.  Is that mean when I use two points constructed from intersection to do intersetion with circle. It could not intersect with the extremal point of circle?